# Can't install M720 Thriatlon on Ubuntu 16.04 lts

Tags: mouse, logitech

I'm a total newbie to Ubuntu but I need it for my deep learning executions.

I can't seem to be able to get a Logitech M720 Triathlon mouse to work with Ubuntu 16.04LTS (neither by wireless key nor Bluetooth).
The Bluetooth seems to link and apparently pair correctly, but then it does not detect the device as a mouse even.
I haven't found a working solution for my case. Any tips on this?

Answer (score 0):

[Solaar](http://pwr.github.io/Solaar/index.html) software let you manage Logitech’s Unifying Receiver with ease. for Ubuntu 16.04LTS, it's available to download from Ubuntu Software.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/695930)

Comment: yes, you're right